# Encoding prob while reading JSON file from URL

Tags: json, node.js, http, encoding

So I am reading a JSON file on a remote server via standard node `http.get`. This JSON contains strings like this: `NÖM Portionsbutter PG=20g 100er`, but on my server this same string looks like this: `N�M Portionsbutter PG=20g 100er`.

The problem, I think, lies in the discrepancy between the header of the http request (`content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8`) and the actual encoding of the JSON file (`ISO-8859-1`).

I tried several versions of fixing this, like using [iconv-lite's](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite) `iconv.decode(data, 'latin1')`, but again, these special chars ("Umlaute" in German) show up wrong.

Fun fact: Downloading the file via the browser, inspecting it via `file -I file.json` and getting `text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1` and then using `iconv.decode(data, 'latin1')` works perfectly fine and the Umlaute are correct.

I am out of ideas right here ... what is the perfect way to properly parse a JSON file like this?

Answer (score 0):

If the server uses an incorrect encoding, it's broken and should be fixed.

(It should use application/json, in which case the charset parameter is undefined/unused).

Answer (score 0):

@Julian Reschke is obviously right but I found a way around this and am now able to read the json with all its Umlaute in it properly.

What I did is use [request's](https://github.com/request/request) `encoding` option and set it to `null`, so `request` is not trying to "parse" the response in any way. I then use `iconv.decode(data, 'latin1')` to set the proper encoding of the day and then `JSON.parse` it. works beautifully!